# Вывод echo по таймеру

Tags: php, таймер

Как можно реализовать вывод `echo` через некоторое время на сайте? Допустим один сразу, а второй через 5 сек. Пытался сделать кодом ниже, но браузер ничего не показывает 5 секунд, а потом сразу оба значения.

```php
<?php
   echo "1";
   sleep(5);
   echo "2";
?>
```

Comment: сервер выдает ответ 1 раз, когда подготовит его. Для вашей задачи нужно использовать JS. Если нужен именно ответ с сервера то нужен AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно не средствами РНР это решать а средствами jQuery или JavaScript

```
<?php
echo <<<HTML
    <p class="p1">1</p>
    <p class="p2" style="display:none">2</p>
HTML;
?>
```

```js
var timer;

$(function(){
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    $('.p2').show();
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p1">1</p>
<p class="p2" style="display:none">2</p>
```